# Sherlock navigation drawer with headers

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

I have an app with Sherlock Actionbar. It has a navigation drawer with a lot of titles, as in this picture:

[image: Picture 1]

I want to make it easier to find the most used titles by making a favorites section. To make that happen, I have to add two headers and a button to the navigation drawer. Just like on this picture:

[image]

I could use some help to make this. Could you tell me how to make it?
My java code:

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] mTitle;
String[] mSubTitle;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle)
        {
    this.context = context;
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mTitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder") public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtSubTitle;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,
            false);

    // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
    txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    // Set the results into TextViews
    String[] title = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
    String[] subtitle = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subtitle);
    txtTitle.setText(title[position]);
    txtSubTitle.setText(subtitle[position]);

    return itemView;
}

}
```